# Find a maximum of a list without constructing the list

Tags: python

I've been playing around with Python for making one-line solutions for some competition problems, and I've run into the following issue. My solution can be written as `max([f(k) for k in range(n)])` (where `f(k)` is some simple expression), which looks great, but when `n` is large it ends up constructing a list before finding its maximum, which exceeds the memory limit. Is there a way to find the maximum without actually constructing the list, while still keeping it down to one line? I know the following works, but if I wanted that I'd just use a different language:

```
best = f(0)
for k in range(n):
  best = max(best, f(k))
return best
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) takes a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) also:

```
max(f(k) for k in range(n))
```

This saves you from having to build the entire list.

Thanks to @DanielRoseman for pointing out that in Python 2.x you should be using `xrange()` instead of `range()`. Recall that `range()` returns a list in Python 2.x, whereas `xrange()` returns an `xrange object` (a constant-memory iterable).

Comment: If this isn't Python 3, you should also be using `xrange` rather than `range` to avoid constructing that list.

Comment: Any iterator actually, including Python 3 `map` (useful if `f` is actually a function rather than an inline expression).

Comment: "`xrange()` returns a generator." --> "xrange() returns an object, xrange object" (*not* generator)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan OK, I guess an `xrange` object isn't technically a generator.

Comment: @arshajii yes, for an example xrange implements getitem whereas generator don't implements, Xrange is just an object that is made lazy purposefully.